# Python: How to login to facebook before making a request using urllib

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to generate an authorization code for using Facebook Ads API. Details for generating authorization code can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview#access_token).

I need to generate this code often so I am planning to do this programmatically. The requested URL opens a dialog box on first ever request by a user. On subsequent requests, the dialog box does not appear and user is redirected to another page where the required code is present in the URL.

SO, my question is: How can I login to facebook and get the URL of the page redirected to.

I have written he following method:

```
def facebook_login():
    username = raw_input("Username:")
    password = getpass.getpass()
    requests.get('https://facebook.com', auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))


def generate_auth_code():
    url = ("").join([BASE_URL,"/dialog/oauth?client_id=",APP_ID,"&redirect_uri=",APP_URL,"&scope=ads_management"])
    facebook_login()
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    print response.geturl()
```

But I get the following output:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=APP_ID&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.1%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252FMY_APP_URL%252F%26scope%3Dads_management%26client_id%CLIENT_ID%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=http%3A%2F%2FMY_APP_URL%2F%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page
```

What is the correct way of doing this